# When an certain error is raised I want to close my WCF Service host

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a scenario where when a certain error occurs we want to shut down the WCF service host. The problem I am having is that when the error occurs on one of the intances how can I get it back to the calling program where the service host is so that I can close it.  I can see the error being thrown when I debug, but it doesn't bubble up to where the service host is called (service host is being opened) in the main program?

What am I missing here? Just don't understand what I need to do so that when that error occurs I can shutdown the WCF Service.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

--S

Comment: Could you please give more details about where the error is raise and why it doesn't go up to the wcf server host (two different programs I suppose) ?

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, the WCF app we have is picking messages off of a queue.  So it is spawning multiple instances.  Even though I am throwing an unhandled error on an instance it does not appear to go up to the host.  I have a catch block on the host that shutdown the service.

Comment: Try making host variable global, and whenever an instance error occurs - call shutdown method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article WCF Error Handling and Fault Conversion on Code Project might help you [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26320/WCF-Error-Handling-and-Fault-Conversion)